# How Do I Set a Breakpoint for Object Instantiation, with No Constructor?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make sense of a class from a library. The class has no constructor, and I think it is being instantiated via reflection. It is a confusing library, and I want to figure out what is creating instances of this class... but I cannot figure out where to put a breakpoint, since there is no constructor.

I have tried the following, and Android Studio 3.4.1 blows right past them:

- Line breakpoints on fields in the class that have initializers
- Field watchpoints, set for both field access and field modification, for fields that have initializers
- A breakpoint on the class declaration (`class Foo`)

Breakpoints in methods work, and field watchpoints work when the field is accessed later on (but not when it is initialized). So the debugger is working with this class in general.

I cannot readily recompile the library to add a constructor, though I do have source code (not just decompiled bytecode).

Is there another spot that I can put a breakpoint that will show me the stack trace of instantiation of this class?

Comment: Have you tried using the memory profiler - record memory allocations - browse list or filter on class name and view call stack for allocations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the InitelliJ IDEA documentation (on which AS is based):

> If you want to set a breakpoint in the default class constructor, set it on the first line of this class, since the default constructor is mapped to it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html

Simple test-case to determine breakpoint position:

```
public class ReflectionTest {
    static int test = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());
    }
}
```

Placing the breakpoint on `public class ReflectionTest` seems to trigger for me.

Comment: If by "the first line of this class", they mean `class Foo`, that did not work. After that there are a few `static` fields. A line breakpoint on the first non-static field does not work. And I don't know what "the first line of this class" would mean otherwise.

Comment: After creating a basic testing class and invoking it through reflection with `class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` it appears the debugger does get triggered after putting the breakpoint on the `public class` line. Are you sure that the constructor even gets invoked in your situation? Some frameworks create non-initialized instances of classes for internal processing.

Comment: "Are you sure that the constructor even gets invoked in your situation?" -- I wasn't aware that "no constructor invocation" was a possibility. Would field initializers still be invoked in that case? "it appears the debugger does get triggered after putting the breakpoint on the public class line" -- that definitely lends credence to your "it's not constructed normally" scenario. And, considering that my situation involves instrumented tests, that's not out of the question. I will do some more research given these notes. Many thanks!

Comment: "Would field initializers still be invoked in that case?" - I dont believe so because the usual use-case for uninitialized objects is deserialization, where the fields get overwritten anyway.

Comment: Then that wouldn't seem to be the case here, as the class has fields with initializers, and those must be getting invoked for the resulting object to work. But, I can run the same sort of test that you did and see what that tells me in terms of my ability to get a breakpoint to work.

Comment: Frameworks usually don't pass uninitialized objects to the user-side. If your code interacts with it the framework has somehow ensured it would work as if it was initialized correctly. So that might not be a good indicator of what is happening.

Comment: Yeah, there must be something special going on with this class that I am investigating. I am able to put a breakpoint on ordinary classes on the `class Foo` line and have it work when a `Foo` instance is created normally or via reflection.